# How can i generate a link out of a specific result from a mysql ajax search form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm trying to make a ajax dropdown search form with suggestions based out of mysql database results. Where if you click the suggestion, it links you to the specific product.

This is the code that i'm currently using that's not working:

The javascript in the head of the html page of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var link;
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
           $.get("./includes/backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
            // Display the returned data in browser
            resultDropdown.html(data);
            link = data;
            if (link == '<p>Geen producten gevonden</p>') {
                return link = '';
            } else {
                link = link.substring(3);
                link = link.substring(0, link.length-4);
                link = "#" + link
            }
    });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
        console.log(link);
        window.location = link;
    });
});
</script>
```

The search form:

```
<center><div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Zoek product..." />
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div></center>
```

The backend search file that runs the mysql querys to search for suggestions

```
    $link = mysqli_connect($server, $gebruiker, $wachtwoord, $database);

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Kon geen verbinding maken. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE naam LIKE ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

        $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';


        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo "<p>" . $row["naam"] . "</p>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>Geen producten gevonden</p>";
            }

        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Kon $sql niet uitvoeren. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

im currently getting this as a link when i search for pizza's:

```
http://localhost/index.php#Pizza Boromea</p><p>Pizza Bolognese</p><p>Pizza Bella Italia</p><p>Pizza Braccio Di Ferro
```

[result from clicking one product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Whf.png)

While im clicking for one product 'pizza boromea' out of the suggestion list...

What im looking for is to make this all work so when you click on as example the pizza boromea, it redirects you to localhost/index.php#pizza boromea.

I hope someone understands my problem and can help me. Thank you already, - Julian.

Comment: The problem is that you're filling `link` with all the products returned by your search. Looks like you want the link to be `#{whatever the contents of the clicked <p> is}`, correct? If that's the case, why not determine the link in your `onclick` handler? `link = "#" + $(this).text();`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you i couldn't come up to this :-)!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted instead of renaming the question title to "SOLVED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By filling your `link` variable from the AJAX response in that way, you will get a link to all search results which is not what you want if the server returns multiple products.

Since the server returns each matching product as `<p>Product name</p>`, you already have an onclick handler for each `<p>` returned by the server and you want your link to match exactly what the content of the clicked `<p>` is, you can just build the link at the moment the `<p>` is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent(".result").empty();

    // "this" refers to the <p> that was clicked
    var link = "#" + $(this).text();

    console.log(link);
    window.location = link;
});
```

Note that I'm defining the `var` inside the onclick handler, there's no longer any need to have a `link` variable in the global scope.